# Probability of Monkey typing keyboard

Tags: probability, statistics

A monkey types at a 26-letter keyboard with one key corresponding to each of the lower-case English letters. Each keystroke is chosen independently and uniformly at random from the 26 possibilities. If the monkey types 1 million letters, what is the expected number of times the sequence "bonbon" appears?

P.S bonbonbon counts as two appearances.

My approach is

Let the indicator $I_B$ be the event that "bonbon" appears, then $P(I_B) = 1/26^6$

Then $E(X) = E(I_{B_1} + I_{B_2} + \dotsb + I_{B_\text{1 million}}) = 1\text{ million} \times 1/26^6$

Is my approach right? Somehow I feel I have done something wrong here.

Comment: Have you searched for ...ehm... [monkey](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17152/)?

Comment: Does `xxbonbonbonbonxx` count as two or three appearances?

Comment: bonbonbon counts as two appearances

Comment: If xxbonbonbonbonxx counts for three, the answer is correct provided you replace one million by one million minus five.

Comment: @percusse, the link corresponds to the title of this post, not to its content.

Comment: @DidierPiau It's a joke!

Comment: Indicator works fine, but one should be precise about the definition. $I_n=1$ if an initial "b" of "bonbon" appears in position $n$.

Comment: You're right. Linearity of expectation is a wonderful thing, particularly since it doesn't depend on the events being independent.

Comment: @DidierPiau, why minus five?

Comment: Because the word `bonbon` has length six hence it cannot begin at position 999,996 or later on and be completely written at position 1,000,000.

Comment: @DidierPiau that makes a lot of sense. Why I didn't think of that. Thanks for the help

Comment: @DidierPiau, you should write this up as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `xxbonbonbonbonxx` counts for three, the answer is correct provided one replaces one million by one million minus five. Why *minus five*? Because the word `bonbon` has length six hence it cannot begin at position 999,996 or later on and be completely written at position 1,000,000.