# What is the probability for a monkey writing Shakespeare?

Tags: probability, statistics

The [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_monkey_theorem) clearly describes the idea but does not the state the probability. What is the probability? Can this problem be extended to audio, graphics and video for instance what is the probability that a random outcome is a certain song, a certain photo or a certain movie?

Comment: Have you seen [this thread](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/10658/264) or [this thread](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/17152/264)?

Comment: would be interesting if a monkey scribbles something and Shakespeare repeats that? Whats the prob of that?

Comment: Wasn't Shakespeare himself a kind of a monkey?  If so, then I guess the probability is 1.

Answer (score 4):

Given enough time I would say 100%.